# Generating unique id's and for JSX element Nodes - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-props, react-key-index

Having a bit of a headache at the moment. I creating a quiz platform using React, and currently, I have a question component, which using , where inside that you can add however many 's as you like. However, I want to make these answers have unique id's for when I submit the quiz to the server (haven't got that far yet).

Where I try to use {this.props.qNo} I get the error: "this: this '...' expected ts(1005)"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Probably something stupid I imagine!

**Individual Answer Components**

```
import React from 'react';

class AnswerText extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }



    render(){
        return (
            <div className="input">
                <label htmlFor="answer1">Answer {this.props.qNo}</label>
                <input name="answer1" type="text" id="answer"{this.props.qNo}></input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="answerCheck" id="answerCheck" ></input>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default AnswerText;
```

**AddTextQuestion code**

```
import React from 'react';
import '../css/addQuestion.css';
import AnswerText from './answerText.js';

class AddTextQuestion extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            noAnswers: 0
        }
        this.addAnswer = this.addAnswer.bind(this);
    }

    addAnswer(){
        this.setState({
            noAnswers: this.state.noAnswers + 1
        })
    }

    render(){

        let answers = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < this.state.noAnswers; i++){
            answers.push(<AnswerText key={i} qNo={i + 1} />)
        }

        return (
        <div className="qContainer">

            <form className="addQForm">
                <div className="questionContainer containers">
                        <h3 className="qNo">Question {this.props.qNo}</h3>
                        <div className="input">
                            <label htmlFor="question">Question</label>
                            <input name="question" type="text" id="question"></input>
                        </div>
                </div>
              
                <div className="answerContainer containers">
                    <button type="button" onClick={this.addAnswer}><i className="material-icons">add</i> Answer</button>
                    {answers}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default AddTextQuestion;
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is

```
 <input name="answer1" type="text" id={`answer${this.props.qNo}`}></input>
```

Is it possible that `id="answer"{this.props.qNo}` throws everything off?

Comment: Thank you Pawel, I knew it would be something stupid! Thanks again.